# asyncio aiohttp errors when threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I have a script written for me and I cannot execute it...I receive the following errors...

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "crawler.py", line 56, in 
>       loop.run_until_complete(future)   File "C:\Users\lisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
>   line 568, in run_until_complete
>       return future.result()   File "crawler.py", line 51, in run
>       await responses   File "crawler.py", line 32, in bound_fetch
>       await fetch(url, session)   File "crawler.py", line 22, in fetch
>       async with session.get(url, headers=headers) as response:   File "C:\Users\lisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py",
>   line 843, in **aenter**
>       self._resp = await self._coro   File "C:\Users\lisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py",
>   line 387, in _request
>       await resp.start(conn)   File "C:\Users\lisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py",
>   line 748, in start
>       message, payload = await self._protocol.read()   File "C:\Users\lisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py",
>   line 533, in read
>       await self._waiter aiohttp.client_exceptions.ServerDisconnectedError: None

Is there something obvious I'm missing?  I can run the same script without threading, thanks...

```
import random
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession
import requests
from itertools import product
from string import *
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import islice
import sys


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

letter = sys.argv[1]
number = int(sys.argv[2])

first_group = product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=2)
second_group = product(digits, repeat=3)
codeList = [''.join([''.join(k) for k in prod]) for prod in product([letter], first_group, second_group)]

async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
        statusCode = response.status
        if(statusCode == 200):
            print("{} statusCode is {}".format(url, statusCode))
        return await response.read()


async def bound_fetch(sem, url, session):
    async with sem:
        await fetch(url, session)

def getUrl(codeIdex):
    return "https://www.blahblah.com/" + codeList[codeIdex] + ".png"

async def run(r):
    tasks = []
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(1000)

    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for i in range(r):
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(sem, getUrl(i), session))
            tasks.append(task)

        responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        await responses

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(number))
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

Comment: Can you reduce the code to a **minimal** example that still reproduces the issue, ideally using a publicly available site that we can test? As shown, your code even has import that it doesn't even use, such as `multiprocessing.Pool`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave comments so i'll write here. Try to set a lower number to semaphore limit, i think the problem is depends on how many requests you are making to the web site at the same time. And you also need to catch errors like that when you are trying to fetch any url if you want to finally get responses from all requests.